# devexpress React Grid table rowSpan

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devexpress

> I want to merge the rows of cells. The merge condition is that when the Region field is equal to America and the Sector field is equal to Banking, they both meet the conditions and need to be merged. Please help me, thanks.

```
 <Paper>
      <Grid rows={rows} columns={columns}>
        <Table />
        <TableHeaderRow />
      </Grid>
  </Paper>
```

this is demo [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-snow-gqc4t9?from-embed=&file=/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

```
const Cell = props => {
const { column, tableRow, value } = props;
if (tableRow.rowId === 1 && (column.name === "region" || column.name === "sector" )) {
    return (
      <Table.Cell {...props} rowSpan={2}>
          {value}
      </Table.Cell>
    );
  }  else if(tableRow.rowId === 2 && (column.name === "region" || column.name === "sector" )) {
  return null;
} else {
    return (
      <Table.Cell {...props}>
          {value}
      </Table.Cell>
    );;
  } 
return (
  <Table.Cell {...props}>
      {value}
  </Table.Cell>
);


};



<Paper>
  <Grid rows={rows} columns={columns}>
    <Table cellComponent={Cell} />
    <TableHeaderRow />
  </Grid>
</Paper>
```